# using perl fetch a .txt file and for every line in that file do something

Tags: linux, perl

I'm pretty new in perl so please try to understand me.
I have in a .txt file defined some lines like this:

```
doc1.20131010.zip
doc2.20131010.zip
doc3.20131010.zip
doc4.20131010.zip
```

I made this code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use autodie;
use Net::SFTP::Attributes;
use Net::SFTP;
use constant {
    HOST            => "x.x.x.x",
    USER_NAME       => "sftptest",
    PASSWORD        => "**********",
    DEBUG           => "0",
};
my $REMOTE_DIR = "IN";
my $LOCAL_DIR  = "/home/rec";
my $sftp = Net::SFTP->new (
    HOST,
    timeout         => 240,
    user            => USER_NAME,
    password        => PASSWORD,
    autodie         => 1,
);

#
# Fetch Files
#
#my $res = $sftp->ls($REMOTE_DIR,sub { print $_[0]{longname}, "\n" });
#print "$res";
my $ls = $sftp->ls($REMOTE_DIR) 
    or die "ls failed: " . $sftp->error;
open my $fh, '>', '/home/rec/listing' or die "unable to create file: $!";
print $fh $_->{filename}, "\n" for @$ls;
close $fh;
open  F, "</home/docs/listing";
for my $line (<F>)
{
    #print "$line";
    $sftp->get("$line","$line") ;
}
```

Now when I run the above code it should give me the above files listed, instead I get this:

```
Couldn't stat remote file: No such file or directory at ./r.pl line 40.
```

Comment: yes, but please tell me more, i don't know at what to look. thanks

Comment: I would like to tell you, but don't know what is content of line 40

Comment: my mistake the content is: $sftp->get("doc1.20131010.zip","doc1.20131010.zip") ;

Comment: When do print "$line"; i get the list of files i have put in the .txt now i would like to do the same, but this time with $sftp->get listing all those files from txt. thanks

Comment: I modified your post by inputing your program, so it's easier to read. When I did this, I noticed your program only has 39 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to remove newline after reading file names from filehandle:

```
for my $line (<F>) {
  chomp($line);
  $sftp->get($line, $line);
}
```

or more commonly,

```
while (my $line = <F>) {
  chomp($line);
  $sftp->get($line, $line);
}
```

Comment: One more thing i would like to ask.
When i'm making ls in the remote sftp server and i write in my .txt the ls output i get this.

    `.
    doc1.20131010.zip
    ..
    doc3.20131010.zip
    doc3.20131010.zip
    doc4.20131010.zip`

How can i tell in the script to ignore the first dot and then the third two dots?

Thanks.

Comment: ``ls -A`` lists all without the implied ``.`` and ``..`` as well.

Comment: @mpapec can you explain more on how to use `@$ls = grep !/^[.]{1,2}$/, @$ls;` and where in those lines ? Thanks.

Comment: @user2866956 put it after `my $ls = ..` Correction: `@$ls = grep $_->{filename} !~ /^[.]{1,2}$/, @$ls;`

Comment: @mpapec Thanks, that was it, now is all perfectly running. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You use `use autodie;`, yet you have:

```
open my $fh, '>', '/home/rec/listing' or die "unable to create file: $!";
```

No need for the `or die...` since the program will automatically die.

You also have `use feature qw(say);`, yet you use `print` instead of `say`. The whole purpose of `say` is to prevent issues that might be the cause of your error.

You also should check the return results of your `$sftp->get($line, $line);` line to see if it was successful or not.

If you did both of these, you would have seen that your `$sftp->get($line, $line)` was failing because you forgot to `chomp` that NL at the end of the file.

Instead, you used:

```
 `print $line;`
```

which printed the file out, but since the file name had a NL, it looked fine. Otherwise, you would have see the extra space and immediately seen the problem.

Comment: Thanks, i fixed the code as you said. Works great!
Now i need to find a way to ignore the dots or not list them at all.